# Answer Correct? In how many ways can one move from (m,n) to (a,b) as directed in question's description?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

**Q**.In 2-D space the point (a,b) is said to be lattice point if both a and b are integers. Two lattice points (a,b) and (c,d) are neighbors if they agree in one of the coordinates and differ in the other coordinate by 1 unit. Every pair of neighbors is connected by a directed line with the direction coinciding with the positive direction of the coordinate axis to which it is parallel?
**In how many ways can one move from (m,n) to (a,b) along the directed path?**

I tried solving it this way:

while going from (m,n) to (a,b)

we have to move $|m-a|$ units in x-axis direction and $|n-b|$ units

let x represent 1 unit in x-axis direction and y represent 1 unit in y-axis direction

therefore, we just need permutations of x,x,x...x,y,y,...,y where total number of x's are $|m-a|$ and total number of y's are $|n-b|$

hence, answer would be

$= [(|m-a|+|n-b|)!]/[(|m-a|])!.(|n-b|)!]$

is this correct? Kindly guide me if I did it wrongly.

Comment: Is this move allowed: (0,0)->(1,0)->(2,0)->(2,1)->(1,1) to go from (0,0) to (1,1)?

Comment: There will also be an infinite number of paths if we're allowed to go too far in one direction and then go back, as in @gunbl4d3's example.

Comment: I have done it assuming we can either
(i) only move parallel to positive x and y axes.
or
(ii) only move parallel to negative x, y axes.(if second point is to the left & below of first)
 I think otherwise there will be infinite ways isn't it ?

Comment: Assuming we are only considering "optimum" paths in the sense that you cannot go far in any direction and then come back I believe the result is correct. It is the number of multiset permutations as stated.

Comment: That is true if you can't go back.